# Could not add root certificate to ssl context error with GRPC on Ubtunu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ssl

I'm trying to run a application that uses SSL for license verification. I get the following error and the application does not progress any further

```
[license] License is for an online pool.
[license] endpoint online.symbtc.net:443, use insecure: false
E0404 22:05:22.807869220   21393 ssl_transport_security.cc:619] Could not add root certificate to ssl context.
E0404 22:05:22.807932048   21393 ssl_transport_security.cc:786] Could not load root certificates.
E0404 22:05:22.813890271   21393 ssl_transport_security.cc:619] Could not add root certificate to ssl context.
E0404 22:05:22.813915754   21393 ssl_transport_security.cc:1691] Cannot load server root certificates.
E0404 22:05:22.814347058   21393 security_connector.cc:1098] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INTERNAL_ERROR.
E0404 22:05:22.814355494   21393 secure_channel_create.cc:121] Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'online.symbtc.net:443'
E0404 22:05:22.814370017   21393 secure_channel_create.cc:154] Failed to create subchannel arguments during subchannel creation.
```

I tried creating a VM and trying the same application and do not see the error there. So there's something I'm missing related to SSL/certificates that I don't understand. I have no issues using apt update or other tasks that maybe SSL dependent. I looked around but could not find any posts on this issue. I've tried updating ca-certificates and checking ssl installation

Please let me know if there are any debug steps that I can take to identify what's going wrong because I do not want to take the reinstall Ubuntu route for now.

Comment: It would be very difficult to offer adivce on how to get this application working without knowing what the application is.  I've tracked the error message down to [one of the open source libraries it uses](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc), but that's not much help.  Could you [edit] into your question the name of the application you are trying to use and relevant configuration?

Comment: Thanks! Updated the title